# How to add headers to ZeroCopyPost

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying to upload an image file to a web storage server using zero copy post.

The implementation comes from the [example](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/httpasyncclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/client/ZeroCopyHttpExchange.java) in the Apache website. I've changed some parts from the example so that the response is not downloaded in a file.

Here's the source code that I have changed.

```
private void upload() throws Exception {

    CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
    try {
        httpclient.start();
        File upload = new File("C:\\Users\\Jee\\profile.png");
        ZeroCopyPost httpost = new ZeroCopyPost(requestURL+upload.getName(), upload,
                ContentType.create("image/png"));
        HttpAsyncResponseConsumer consumer = new BasicAsyncResponseConsumer();
        Future<File> future = httpclient.execute(httpost, consumer, null);
        File result = future.get();
        System.out.println("Response file length: " + result.length());
        System.out.println("Shutting down");
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

I need to add headers to this POST request. How is it done?

Comment: try extending the class and adding your own implementation of 'generate Request'. Here , before returning the Request, you can add an ArrayList<String> of your request headers. that should be available in the API for <Request>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ZeroCopyPost zeroCopyPost = new ZeroCopyPost(
        URI.create("/"),
        new File("stuff"),
        ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY) {

    @Override
    protected HttpEntityEnclosingRequest createRequest(
            final URI requestURI, final HttpEntity entity) {
        HttpEntityEnclosingRequest request = super.createRequest(requestURI, entity);
        request.setHeader("my-header", "whatever");
        return request;
    }
};
```

Overriding ZeroCopyPost#createRequest is the recommended way. Overriding #generateRequest per @Robert Rowntree recommendation would work as well.